# Installing Azure Module on an AWS instance using userdata

Tags: azure, powershell, amazon-ec2, module, user-data

I'm trying to automatically install the Azure module for PowerShell (Az) on an AWS EC2 instance through userdata so Azure commands can be executed when an instance is started. However, I'm getting this error:

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : Cannot convert value
>   "2.0.0-preview" to type "System.Version". Error: "Input string was 
>   not in a correct format."

Other people who have reported this problem have solved it by upgrading PowerShellGet and removing the old version. I'm doing that with this block of code:

```
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force -Confirm:$false
    Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Repository PSGallery -Force -Confirm:$false
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1" -Force -Recurse
```

However when I run the command to install the moudule after that:

```
    Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force -Confirm:$false -Scope AllUsers
```

I still get the same error.

How can I fix this without having to close and reopen the shell? This all needs to run as part of the same script.

Answer (score 0):

You used `Remove-Item`, however that command just deleted the module file. The imported module still existed in your PS session. So, you may try to use `Remove-Module` remove it and use `Import-Module` to import the right one.  But, this is not the suggested way, you may try the following two approaches:

1. You can just use `Update-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force` to directly update your existing module.
2. Another way is to uninstall your old module, and then install the new version.

Comment: Thanks veru much for your suggestion, Jack, but even after the update has succeeded I'm still receiving the same error message.

Comment: Run `Get-InstalledModule` to check the installed version.